# What are the properties of the roots of the incomplete/finite exponential series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, roots, exponential-function

Playing around with the incomplete/finite exponential series

$$f_N(x) := \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{z^k}{k!} \stackrel{N\to\infty}\longrightarrow e^z$$

for some values on [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) (e.g. [`solve sum_(k=0)^19 z^k/(k!) = 0  for  z`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20sum_%28k=0%29%5E19%20z%5Ek/%28k!%29%20=%200%20%20for%20%20z)), I made a few observations:

- The sum of the roots of $f_N$ are $-N$
- The product of the roots of $f_N$ are $(-1)^N\cdot N!$
- Their imaginary part seems to lie between $\pm10$
- The zeros seem to form an interesting shape:

[image]
Patterns for $N=17, 18, 19$

Now the sum and product part are clear, since

$$\begin{align}
  f_N(x) &= \frac1{N!}\left(z^N + N z^{N-1} + N(N-1)z^{N-2} + ... + N!\right)
\\ &= \frac1{N!}(z-z_{N0})(z-z_{N1})\cdots(z-z_{NN})
\\ &= \frac1{N!}\left(z^N - \left(\sum_{k=0}^Nz_{Nk}\right) z^{N-1} + ... + (-1)^N\prod_{k=0}^N z_{NK}\right)
\end{align}$$

and since $e^z=0 \Leftarrow \Re z\to-\infty$ it is clear that the roots tend towards real parts with negative infinity, but I'm still intrigued by the questions

> what ($N$-dependent) curve do the zeros of $f_N(z)$ lie on, does that curve maintain its shape for varying $N$ and merely translate or also deform; and what other properties of the zeros (e.g. absolute value) can be derived?

Comment: @martini Thanks, how did you fix thi-- I see, you escaped most characters, did you use a tool for that or do it manually?

Comment: I used the "add a link" feature of the edit/answer window here on SE. Just click on the "chain" and paste the link there ...

Comment: @martini [m-/](http://picardfacepalm.com/) I never used that feature until now, always manually linked via `[]()`... Thanks!

Comment: You may also be interested in these three questions: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/109360/5531), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/131479/5531), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51586/5531).

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks, interesting indeed!

Comment: Related MO-question: [Roots of truncations of $e^x - 1$](http://mathoverflow.net/q/4329/6797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zeros of the scaled functions $f_N(Nz)$ do converge to an airfoil-like curve.
See an animation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109605/589).

See also these:

- [Zeros of truncated Taylor series](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~millerpd/docs/557_Winter13/D_Jonas.pdf) by Jonas (see the references at the end) (2013)
- [Zeroes of the partial sums of the exponential function](http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Ian.pdf) by Zemke (2009)
- [On the zeroes of the nth partial sum of the exponential series](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30037629) by Zemyan (2005)
- [The zeros of the partial sums of the exponential series](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3647884) by Walker (2003)

Comment: Awesome links, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps an interesting relation: there is a proposition of a function as 2-fold iteration $f_c(z)=c^z  \text{ with } c,z \in \mathbb C$ and a method to find periodic-points $f^{o2}_c(z)=z$ with a function called "HyperW()" or $HW()$ in an article as a generalization of the Lambert-W. The method to actually approximate periodic points means to solve the ***truncated*** taylor-series of $f^{o2}_c(z)$ . This is a strong relation to the subject here. I've done some investigation. See question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3706909 and one answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3713978 .

Answer (score 3):

One more picture; here I rescale the radial distances from the origin to their logarithm; the roots of the polynomials $f_{16},f_{32},f_{64},f_{128}$ are shown, the magenta line is that for $f_{16}$. I find it interesting, that the radial positions fit nicely together, see the straight lines from the origin (the roots do not exactly match with the lines but remarkably good)

[image]

Comment: So in other words, you plot on a log-log scale, right? Wow, that's an interesting observation! Also interesting: The amount of roots between two such lines appears to be of the form $2^n-1$

Comment: Well, that's not quite the correct transformation. In fact, if I do separately rescale the x-axis and the y-axis, then the curves approximate squares (you might try this using an asinh-scaling instead, which becomes quite similar to a log-log-scaling for values >1). No, here I compute the polar coordinates of the roots, rescale the distance to the origin $\sqrt{\Re(\rho)^2+\Im(\rho)^2}= |\rho| $ by logarithmizing and recalc the rectangular coordinates from that.

Comment: @tobias:the number of roots between two such lines plus that *on* one line is just 2^<index-of-line> because the number of complex roots is just doubling with each step.

Comment: Ah true, it's too early in the morning... I wonder if the roots _really_ don't lie exactly on these line or whether that's numerical accuracy... Also, the real roots seem to be very regularly spaced

Comment: @Tobias: Yepp. Do you have Pari/GP? It was no problem to get the 128 roots by the simple call <pre> polroots(Pol(exp(x) + O( x^2^7)))) </pre> in just a second.(One should increase the default powerseries precision and the computing precision sufficiently high)

Comment: I'm usually using Python or Wolfram Alpha, but I'll have a look at it, thanks!