# Show that the closest zero of a sequence of polynomials obtain a lower bound

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^k}{k!}$. Let $z_n$ be the zero of $f_n$ which is closest to the origin, and prove that $\|z_n\| \geq tn$ for some constant $t$.

First of all, the statement makes perfect sense. Since $f_n$ is the partial sum of the power series expansion of $e^z$ which has no zero at all. So by Hurwitz theorem, the zeros of $f_n$ have to be pushed out. However, I do not know how to make the bound precise.

I do not really think this is the duplicate of the question asked. Since as I explained above using Hurwitz is enough to show that $f_n(z)$ cannot have zeros inside a given compact set for large enough $n$. But here I want a precise bound for $\|z_n\|$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109360/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51586/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1467219/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535720/115115 and further links therein.

Comment: How can I get rid of this duplicate stuff T T

Comment: Either you find an your answer in the given links and their links or you make your question more precise based on the ideas presented there. The voters think the linked answers are sufficient to answer your question.