# Taylor expansion of exponential function and singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Stackexchange community,

i have a little trouble in understanding this condradtiction about singularities.

Lets consider the function $f(z)=\exp(-z)$.

This function can be expanded as a taylor series:

$$f(z)=1-z+\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{z^3}{3!}\pm$$

As this is "some sort of polynomial" it will never have a singularity on every finite domain of $z$.

But if I express $f(z)=\exp(-z)=\frac{1}{\exp(z)}$ and then apply the taylor series on $\exp(z)$ I get:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}\pm}$$

Now here comes my confusion, the new representation allows singularities of $f(z)$, as it is "some kind of polynomial" in the denominator. What is the problem here? Is it because of the radius of convergence?

EDIT: Ok it is because the fundamental theorem of calculus isn't true for infinite sums. Is there some intuitive way of understanding this phenomenon?

I would be glad if someone could solve this contradicion.

Comment: But what is the problem with second representation?

Comment: The second representation allows singularities by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: "As this is a polynomial" -- no it is not a polynomial.

Comment: Ok it is power sum, but why exactly does the fundamental theorem of algebra not hold for infinite polynomials?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109360/roots-of-the-incomplete-gamma-function/109605#109605 for the behaviour of the roots of the partial sums of the exponential function. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/approximating-roots-of-the-truncated-taylor-series-of-exp-by-values-of-the-la/553357#553357

Answer (score 1):

It is *not*
"some sort of polynomial."
It is a power series
with an infinite number of terms.

Consider the polynomials
$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k
$
for any positive integer $k$
these are defined
for all real (and complex)
$x$.

But, if we consider
the infinite power series
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k
$,
this diverges for
$|x| > 1$
and converges for
$|x| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

the denominator is never 0. no singularities